How do I implement an angular component in ASP.NET CORE web app MVC
The first question is whether this is even possible. I've searched extensively online but couldn't find any useful information. Specifically, I'm wondering how to add an Angular component into an ASP.NET Core MVC project. I have a button that I'd like to implement, but I'm not sure how to proceed. To clarify, I prefer using Angular components because my website has many buttons, and I'd rather not repeatedly supply the same class attributes. I'm looking to apply this approach not just for buttons, but for all frequently used components on my website. Ideally, I'd like my ASP.NET Core MVC HTML to include Angular components like <app-button [label]="label" (clickEvent)="event()" /> and similar code snippets for other components. Thank you to everyone who can offer guidance.
I've tried searching on YouTube and Stack Overflow but still couldn't find any useful information.

Have you considered using Angular Elements? https://angular.io/guide/elements#angular-elements-overview

Can you show some of the results you found while searching and explain how they are not relevant to your question? A few seconds of Google finds Angular MVC implementations with components.
